# Programmatic segues for pages not working as expected on Watch

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos

I have 5 interface controllers in my Watch extension app:

```
[1]InterfaceController (entry point)
[2]InterfaceController 
[3]InterfaceController
[4]InterfaceController
[5]InterfaceController
```

I'd like the user to be able to swipe from [1] to [2], so I created a segue in the Interface.storyboard.  This works fine when I first go into the app -- I see two dots at the bottom of the screen [1] and can swipe between it and screen [2]. Screen [1] has a button that brings the user to the screen [3].  I'm using this call which works:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: 
["[3]InterfaceController"], contexts: [])
```

Likewise, when I tap the button from the screen [3] to the screen [4], I'm using this call which works, too :

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: 
["[4]InterfaceController"], contexts: [])
```

On the screen [5], I have a button that contains this call:

```
a) WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: 
["[1]InterfaceController", "[2]InterfaceController"], contexts: 
nil, orientation: .vertical, pageIndex: 0)
```

I also tried...

b)

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: 
["[1]InterfaceController", "[2]InterfaceController"], contexts: [])
```

In both cases, when I tap the button off the screen [5], I see the [1]InterfaceController, but the [2]InterfaceController isn't present so I can't swipe to get to it.   What's even stranger, is for a) I see no indication of pages, there's no "dots" at the bottom of the screen [1].  However, for b) I see one dot (I should see two) on screen [1] but I don't see the second dot and can't swipe to screen [2].

Any idea what's going on and how to solve this?

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, I got rid of this UI approach a long time ago.  It must be solvable as I believe I've seen other Watch apps do it.  I may try it again with the latest watchOS release soon...